# Choose Intel syntax for perf report assembly

Tags: x86, disassembly, perf, intel-syntax

My `perf` report shows everything in AT&T syntax:

```
...
0,18 │      pop         %rax                      
0,14 │    ← retq                                  
0,18 │a9:   vmovsd      -0x8(%rdi,%rsi,8),%xmm0   
0,12 │af:   pop         %rax                      
     │    ← retq                                  
     │b1:   vxorpd      %xmm2,%xmm2,%xmm2       
0,02 │      vxorpd      %xmm3,%xmm3,%xmm3       
     │b9:   vmovsd      0x8(%rdi,%rax,8),%xmm4  
0,82 │      vmulsd      %xmm1,%xmm1,%xmm1       
0,16 │      vsubsd      %xmm3,%xmm1,%xmm1       
0,96 │      vsubsd      %xmm2,%xmm4,%xmm3       
0,57 │      vmulsd      %xmm3,%xmm0,%xmm0       
5,34 │      vdivsd      %xmm1,%xmm0,%xmm0       
0,55 │      vaddsd      %xmm0,%xmm2,%xmm0      
...
```

But it's hard to me to read this, I'm more familiar with Intel syntax.

Is there any way to make perf output it in Intel syntax? I've tried to google for manuals but didn't find any flag to enable this mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`perf report -Mintel` gives you GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` disassembly,
just like `objdump -drwC -Mintel`

From [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html)

> `-M`, `--disassembler-style=`
> Set disassembler style for objdump.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't get that `style` means syntax.